# How to Jquery show only a particular td from this table structure?

Tags: jquery, html-table, selection

I  don't know how to query this one out.

I have a table structure that looks like this:

```
<table class="wba_main_table" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="display: none;" id="wba_logo_bg">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="display: none;" class="line">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="wba_topnavBG">
          <table>
          <tr><td>bla bla bla</td></tr> 
          </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="display: none;" class="line">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;" class="greyBar">
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="display: none;" class="line">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="display: none;" class="lightGreyBar">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td><table><tbody><tr><td>
                 <div id="deep_div1"></div>
             </td></tr></tbody></table></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

And what I wanted to do was to hide all the tr except for the one containing the `wba_topnavBG`. My strategy was to use the `wba_logo_bg` as id and select the parents then from there select all the children td which doesn't have the class `wba_topnavBG` and `hide()` them all, but I don't know how to write the selection part.

Any help? :)

### Edit

Forgot to add that inside that td there's another table structure with more tr and tds.

### Edit 2

Mmm, it appears now that I have to hide another tr which contains a table which contains a div with an id. can the jquery line be modified to add another thing to look for in it's :has syntax?

1. How can I hide the other tr except
   for the one containing div `deep_div1` 
   and the one with td class
   `wba_topnavBG`?

As this new twist is still related to this question, I don't want to create another question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the [`:not`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has) and [`:has`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has) pseudo-selectors:

```
$('.wba_main_table tr:not(:has(td.wba_topnavBG))').hide();
```

This selector will match all the `tr` elements that do not contain a `td` element with class `wba_topnavBG`.

Check an example with your markup [here](http://jsbin.com/awowi).

**Edit:** In response to your comment, if you have a table inside that `td`, and you only want to select the direct `tr` descendants of `.wba_main_table`, you should use the [parent > child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child) selector:

```
$('.wba_main_table > tr:not(:has(td.wba_topnavBG))').hide();
```